# putty on monitor rotated 270 degree scrolls slowly

Tags: putty

i am using a two monitor setup

1 monitor is rotated to be in portrait orientation.

when i switch putty to this monitor, the terminal becomes slow. the command line is slow, vim editing is slow.

but if i change the orientation to landscape (0 degree rotated) it seems normal.

```
$ ls -al
```

is there any settings in Windows or in Putty i can change to make it not slow down?